# Jsoup Login to avoid 401 HttpStatusException

Tags: java, html, http, jsoup, http-status-code-401

I am making a program for use at my work that extracts lead info from our HTML lead screen. In order to do so, I am using Jsoup to parse the HTML document and search for the specified information. When I go to pull up the page through my web browser like normal, it prompts me with a login before actually connecting to and loading the page. This poses a problem for Jsoup, as when I go to create a `Document` from a connection, it throws an HttpStatusException for a 401 error, since it's not logging in, and thus, never being authorized to access the page. This is the code I currently have as an example to extract the first name of a lead on the page:

```
package com.brandon.MagnaScraper;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class MagnaScraper {
    public Document getLeadPageConnection(long leadNumber) throws IOException {
        String url = MagnaUrl.LEAD.getUrl() + String.valueOf(leadNumber);
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        return doc;
    }

    public Document getSurveyPageConnection(long surveyNumber) throws IOException {
        String url = MagnaUrl.SURVEY.getUrl() + String.valueOf(surveyNumber);
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        return doc;
    }

    public String getName1(long leadNumber) {
        try {
            Document doc = getLeadPageConnection(leadNumber);
            Element firstNameElement = doc.select("[name=FName1]").first();
            String firstName1 = firstNameElement.attr("value");
            return firstName1;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Error!";
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can have Jsoup input my login credentials in order to gain authorization to connect to the page? I am almost certain this is the reason for the HttpStatusException. Thanks in advance for the help!